# Ifstream Read Not working in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, ifstream

So the read is working for Windows but it's not working for Linux. In GDB the ulTop variable is shown as 0 even though it should be 512 (the value of Constants::INITIAL_READ_SIZE).

```
std::basic_ifstream<unsigned char> file (szFileName, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

if (!file)
{
    if (m_iDisplayType != ConsoleOutput::NO_DISPLAY)
    {
        std::cout << "There was a problem opening the file." << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }
    return false;
}

long lFileSize;

// Grab the file size
file.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
lFileSize = file.tellg();
file.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg );

unsigned long ulTop = 0; // how much of the file is in the pszBuffer

// Do an initial read of the file, to get some data in our pszBuffer, ready for processing...
file.read( &m_szContents[ ulTop ], Constants::INITIAL_READ_SIZE );
ulTop += file.gcount();
memcpy(m_szPcapHeader, m_szContents, Constants::PCAP_HEADER_SIZE);
```

Weird thing is it prints out the correct file size, but ulTop after the increment from file.gcount() is 0 - in Windows it's correctly 512. I really can't figure out what's happening. Any ideas?

Thanks

PS: m_szContents is an unsigned char m_szContents [Constants::LARGE_BUFFER_SIZE] and ulTop is an unsigned long.

Comment: What is m_szContents? And ulTop? You should post the entire relevant code if you need help

Comment: m_szContents is an unsigned char array (a buffer basically) and ulTop is just an unsigned long.

Comment: Anyone have an idea?...

Comment: What about INITIAL_READ_SIZE?

Comment: INITIAL_READ_SIZE is a static const int.

Comment: get the error state flags in linux after the reading and see what happens (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/). Also: double check your #ifdef in case you have some (there's none in your code)

Comment: Will check the flags. What happens if it is one of them? Is there an explanation why it would happen in Linux and not Windows?

Comment: PS: file.good() comes back as true...